# layout_alignTop centrally aligned item is not considered

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

There is the following snippet:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_guest"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/avatar_map_size_listview"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/avatar_map_size_listview"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/image_guest"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/image_guest"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The parent is in wrap_content and there is a 100dp view. The problem is that since the image_guest is `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` and the parent in wrap the icon does not align to image_guest.

How can I align icon to the top of image_guest?

The parent should always be in wrap_content.

**Edit**

What's happening:

[image]

Comment: do you want to display the icon above image_guest or do you want to display it over the image_guest?

Comment: @Dara overlay it on the top right of the image

Comment: @DerGolem please read again. The problem is in vertical not horizontal

Comment: This seems to be a bug. Anyway, you can use FrameLayout to wrap the 2 image view, then set the second image view to top right.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to *image_guest* ImageView.

You may also need to set some negative margin on icon to achieve the expected result.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Still same behaviour